# How to set spark.task.resource.gpu.amount in Dataproc?

Tags: tensorflow, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to run Tensorflow MirroredStrategyRunner ([Reference](https://github.com/tensorflow/ecosystem/blob/master/spark/spark-tensorflow-distributor/spark_tensorflow_distributor/mirrored_strategy_runner.py)) on Google Dataproc. While running this I ran into the error:

```py
Exception: Your cluster might not have Spark GPU-aware scheduling enabled, please contact your cluster administrator.The conf `spark.task.resource.gpu.amount` was not found in the Spark configuration.
```

This error is raised by [L154](https://github.com/tensorflow/ecosystem/blob/c39378894bf080843a86edacd0176c53f70d939f/spark/spark-tensorflow-distributor/spark_tensorflow_distributor/mirrored_strategy_runner.py#L154). This happens because `self.sc.getConf().contains('spark.task.resource.gpu.amount')` does not exist, and `spark.task.resource.gpu.amount` needs to be set.

Now, I tried doing so, using

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("YourAppName") \
    .config("spark.task.resource.gpu.amount", "1") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

However, that gave the error:

```py
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: No executor resource configs were not specified for the following task configs: gpu
```

I also tried using `DataprocInstantiateInlineWorkflowTemplateOperator`, and added the line

```py
"properties": {
                        "spark.task.resource.gpu.amount": "1"
              },
```

in the template under `PySparkJob` as

```py
"jobs": [
            {
                "step_id": "<StepName>",
                "pyspark_job": {
                    "args": [
                        <ListOfArguments>
                    ],
                    "main_python_file_uri": "<ScriptName>",
                    "properties": {
                        "spark.task.resource.gpu.amount": "1"
                    },
                    "jar_file_uris": [
                        "gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar",
                        "gs://onedemand-analytics/jars/spark-tensorflow-connector_2.12-1.11.0.jar",
                    ],
                },
            }
        ]
```

But this gives the error:

```py
TypeError: 1 has type int, but expected one of: bytes, unicode.
```

---

How do we properly set `spark.task.resource.gpu.amount` in the following cases:

1. `gcloud dataproc clusters create` command and then inside script?
2. Template using `DataprocInstantiateInlineWorkflowTemplateOperator`

Comment: Could you try adding this `spark.task.resource.gpu.amount` in the property flag while creating dataproc cluster as mentioning in the [document](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/blob/master/rapids/README.md#step-1-create-dataproc-cluster-with-rapids-accelerator-for-apache-spark).